# How to solve a system of equations which includes vectors?

Tags: equation-solving, vector

I'm starting to wonder if this is something that mathematica just can't do? I thought something like this might work:

```
Reduce[(p0 | pt | v0 | vt | a1 | a2) \[Element] Vectors[3, Reals]
  && (t1 | t2 | k) \[Element] Reals
  && v0 + a1*t1 == vt - a2*t2
  && p0 + v0*t1 + 1/2*a1*t1^2 == pt - (v0 + a1*t1)*t2 - 1/2*a2*t2^2
  && Norm[a1] == k
  && Norm[a2] == k
  && t1 >= 0
  && t2 >= 0,
 {a1, a2, t1, t2}]
```

But I get this:

> Reduce::elemc: Unable to resolve the domain or region membership
>   condition (p0|pt|v0|vt|a1|a2)[Element]Vectors[3,Reals]. >>

I'm interpreting this to mean that Reduce can't handle vectors? I read a suggestion about specifying the components for all the vectors but this is already complex enough, if I did that it would be enormous.

Comment: BTW The second $Assumptions line overwrites the first and doesn't add to the assumptions.

Comment: @Jens Thanks. I've edited the question so it doesn't have that issue, but now there's a different issue.